# Nome de arquivo vindos de um txt e arquivos. Há diferença numa comparação?

Tags: c#

Criei uma lista com 13 nomes de arquivos, que extraí usando o GetFileName().
Outra lista eu quebrei um arquivo txt e carreguei esses nomes em outra lista. Então tenho isso:

```
ListaNomeArquivo

ListaNomeTxt
```

Preciso pegar o nome da lista ListaNomeArquivo e ver se existe dentro de ListaNomeTxt. Tanto Contains quanto Equals, sempre retorna diferente e tenho os mesmos nomes. Só para exemplificar.
Tenho em ambas as listas esse nome:

```
web\\ace\\asp\\ace0003a.asp
```

Acontece que a lambda que fiz, diz que são diferentes:

```
 var busca = listaCommiter.Where(l => !l.Contains(listaFarm.ToString()));
```

Como eu faço para somente armazenar o que realmente não existe?

O código completo dessa rotina:

```
private List<string> ComparaArquivo()
        {
            List<string> listaCommiter = new List<string>();
            List<string> listaFarm = new List<string>();
            List<string> listaDiferenca = new List<string>();

            try
            {
                listaCommiter = _listaCommiter();
                listaFarm = _listaFarm();

                var busca = listaCommiter.Where(l => !l.Contains(listaFarm.ToString()));                

                return listaDiferenca;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                string r = ex.Message;
                return null;
            }

        }
```

A lista em `return listaDiferenca;` está retornando nada, porque estou ainda desenvolvendo. Ela vai retorna `busca`.

Comment: Mas você quer retornar apenas o que tem em `listaFarm` e não tem em `listaCommiter` ou tudo aquilo que não estiver em ambos?

Answer (score 1):

Precisamente para este caso, utilize o [`Except`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
var busca = listaCommiter.Except(listaFarm);
```

Ele vai retornar em **busca**, tudo de `listaCommiter` que não existe na `listaFarm`.

Answer (score 1):

Para retornar apenas o que tem em `listaFarm` mas não está em `listaCommiter`, basta reformular a sua query:

```
var diferenca = listaCommiter.Where(l => !listaFarm.Contains(l));
```

Você pode também usar o [`Enumerable.Except<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>, IEnumerable<TSource>)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779(v=vs.100).aspx)

```
var diferenca = listaCommiter.Except(listaFarm);
```

Caso ainda queira apenas o que é comum entre os dois, você pode utilizar o [`Enumerable.Intersect<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>, IEnumerable<TSource>)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136(v=vs.100).aspx)

```
var comum = listaCommiter.Intersect(listaFarm);
```

Espero ter ajudado \o/